# Left margin problem while printing an html document

Tags: html, css, printing, pyqt5

So i am trying to print a auto generated HTML page through my POS (Thermal) printer, my app is written in PyQt5 and i wore a hacky python script to generate the HTML code but in the print preview the is a huge left margin and it appears on the paper as well after printing. I cannot adjust the left margin through the window and all i can do is edit the html code to work around it.  Here is the generated html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><title> Recipt #12345678 </title>
<style>
html,body  {font-family: "Fake Receipt", sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;}
@page {
    margin: 1cm;
}
</style>
</head><body><h3 >Dyestuff</h3>
        <p >Colours, Threads & Chemicals <br/>
        some@gmail.com |  <b>+91 00000000000</b><br/>
        <b>GSTIN</b>-000000000000000000 <br/>
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p><hr/><h8><b>Transaction Id</b></h8>:  1561324761<br/><h8><b>Date</b></h8>:  Mon Jun 24 02:49:21 2019<br/><h8><b>Billed by</b></h8>:  admin<br/><h8><b>Payment Type</b></h8>:  current<br/><h8><b>Total Amount</b></h8>:  637.1759999999999<br/><h8><b>Client</b></h8>:  0<br/><br/><hr/><table ><tr><th>Product</th><th>HSN</th><th>Qty(U)</th><th>Rate/U</th><th>Tax</th><th>Total</th></tr><tr><td>Magenta Dark</td><td>GTI4</td><td>6.458Kgs</td><td>60</td><td>77.49600000000001</td><td>464.976</td></tr><tr><td>Normal Green</td><td>CAB8</td><td>8.2Kgs</td><td>20</td><td>8.200000000000001</td><td>172.2</td></tr></td></tr></table>
<br/><br/>
<b>GRAND TOTAL: </b>637.1759999999999 Rupees
<p  style='font-size:10px;'><b>Note:</b> The grand total amt is inclusive of all taxes.</br>
Incase of any glitch in amount,tax,etcetera, contact the seller.</p>
</body></html>
```

And the right margin looks like this (Note:there is no right margin because of whitespace):

[image: Image showing huge left margin and no right margin]

So, i just wanted suggestions to fix the html code for it to work.

> Note: The page looks fine in the html browser but bad in the print preview.

**I have tried @page { size:w h; margis } etc to no avail.**

Answer (score 1):

You have a CSS `margin` of `1cm` in your **[`@page`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page)** media query.
This only applies to print, and is responsible for your left margin.

Removing this will bring your text to the left (and move it up the page a bit as well).
If you still want the top margin, you can change this to `margin-top` instead.

Comment: Removing that doesn't helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@media print` instead of `@page` media query for styling.

```
@media print { body { margin: 1cm; } }
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, again to no avail. Though this solution works for others but not for me.